# Work and energy question along circle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, work

[image]

The 10N force is in a constant direction, but when calculating work we need the angle between the force and the direction of movement. Here the direction of movement (the tangent to the circle) is changing, it is a function of the position on the circle.

However, in the solution, the work of the 10N force was calculated like this:

$Fcos(60)*0.2-Fsin(60)*0.2$

What does that mean? How is 0.2m the distance that the force was applied and how is that true for changing angle?

We don't calculate work using integral and dot product of vectors. all the questions should be constant angles and forces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

As you can see from the image, Net force acting on the particle is given by
$$\vec{F}_{net} = \vec{F}\cos(60) \vec{i} + [m\vec{g} - \vec{F}\sin(60)] \vec{j}$$

Displacement in $\vec{j}$ direction is 200mm and same is the displacement in $\vec{i}$ direction too.

Work done by a constant force is given by
$$W_d = \vec{F}.\vec{S}$$, where S is the displacement vector

Thus
$$W_d = (F\cos(60))(0.2) + [m\vec{g} - F\sin(60)](0.2)$$

If you want to find work done only by the 10N force, then it is

$$W_{F} = [F\cos(60)](0.2) - [F\sin(60)](0.2)$$

The negative is because displacement is downwards and the component of force is acting upwards, thus while dotting them the $\cos(180)$ gives the negative sign.

Comment: Generally speaking, negative work means the force is removing energy out of the system? Because here the force in the Y axis is lowering kinetic energy because it is opposite to the direction of movement, but at the same time it is "doing work against gravity" so that it gives potential energy. So the force in the Y axis is only converting energy but not removing it out of the system since there is no friction. Why is that still negative work?

Comment: It is not removing energy. Energy cannot be removed from a system. Even in the case of friction it is given off as heat. The particle started from rest thus the forces are increasing the kinetic energy of the system by reducing the potential energy, here by system I mean Earth + Collar. You cant give energy to something. Potential energy is just the energy possessed by it due to its location in space. In this case it is getting decreased which is getting converted to kinetic energy of the collar.

Comment: If you think in terms of force, then earth is pulling the particle down but F is trying to pull it up, since F cant overcome earth's pull, the particle moves down, thus F is doing negative work and earth is doing positive work. In terms of energy, since the gravitational potential energy of the system decreases, according to law of conservation of energy we get that its kinetic energy should increase though in this case not all the potential energy is getting converted to kinetic energy, some part of the potential energy is being used to resist the work done by F. Hope you are clear

Comment: What do you mean by "you can't give energy to something"? If i add a force which is doing work to the system, it is not adding energy to the system?

Comment: Nope. It is altering the energy already present in the system, in this case the energy already present in the system is gravitational potential energy.

Answer (score 0):

You can parametrize quarter of the circle using$$\vec{r}=0.2sin(\theta)+0.2cos(\theta)$$
Taking the derivative of r w.r.t theta gives
$$\vec{dr}=0.2cos(\theta)d{\theta}-0.2sin(\theta)d{\theta}$$
$$\vec{F}_{net}=10cos(60°)\hat{i}+(0.5×9.8-5\sqrt{3})\hat{j}$$

Net Work=$$\int_{C}\vec{F}.\vec{dr}=1+(9.8/10-\sqrt{3})=0.247..J$$
For theta varying between 0 to pi/2

Using work-energy theorem
$$0.247J=0.5(V_b)^2/2$$
$$|V_b|=0.9967$$